# How do I resolve the ActivityNotFoundException?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm getting an ActivityNotFoundException in my Android Application.. Here's the code snippet I have put to call the activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("NAME", username.getText().toString());
i.setClassName(getPackageName(), SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName());
startActivity(i);
```

my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rangde"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".firstActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".WelcomeActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I execute the code snippet with the intent, I get the following exception.

> E/AndroidRuntime(731): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class {com.rangde/WelcomeActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   //set your classname here
  Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("NAME", username.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Jackson - thanks - but why doesn't the setClassName work the way I have defined it?

Answer (score 0):

Call your SecondActvity like This

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("NAME", username.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 String packageName = this.getPackageName();
 i.setClassName(packageName ,packageName  + "." + SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

instead of

```
i.setClassName(getPackageName(), SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

Comment: you are missing full activity path in second parameter so pass package name + activity name in second activity

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
i.setClassName(getPackageName(), SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

try with

```
i.setClassName(getPackageName(), SecondActivity.class.getName());
```

**SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName()** returns only name of the class.

if u write **SecondActivity.class.getName()** get fully qualified class name(with the package name)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Class1.this, Class2.class);

i.putExtra("NAME", username.getText().toString());

startActivity(intent);
```